# How to open a result of the filled form after the "submit" in a new window?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

Enviroment: Visual Studio 2012, MVC4, Razor.
My code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
        <fieldset>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>

            <p><input name="action:FirstResult" type="submit" value="ResultOne" /></p>
            <p><input name="action:SecondResult" type="submit" value="ResultTwo" /></p>
       </fieldset>
    }
```

The problem is - I have two Submit Buttons. And they are sending the information to the different views. And I want that views in new windows.
I've tried to insert "`new{target = "_blank"}`" inside the "`@using (Html.BeginForm())`", and it is doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code as follows to solve your problem

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FirstAction","Controller"))
    {
<input  type="submit" value="ResultOne" />
    }

@using (Html.BeginForm("SecondAction","Controller"))
    {
<input  type="submit" value="ResultTwo" />
    }
```

Regards,
Pavan.G

Comment: I have input fields on this page. "Submit" buttons must be under the same "Html.BeginForm".

Comment: Yes, Submit buttons should be under the forms.Did you make any attempt on this?